# Visual Stuio 2015 Xamarin Form Portble Project deploy to iPad Failed

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I deploy to my ipad, but appear this message as below:

No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We usually see this error when you do not have any code signing keys/provisional profiles set up on your Mac.

You can find the instructions to set up your machine for iOS development here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/